# Is there a way to write a BLOB using Spring Integration's jdbc:oubound-channel-adapter?

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-integration

I have incoming messages which have String payloads, but the database, (which I do not control), records this data as BLOBs.  Is there a way to get Spring Integration to massage a String into a CLOB or BLOB?

I have an outbound-channel-adapter doing a database insert, which (simplified) looks like:

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter channel="inboundTraffic"
                                   datasource="localDataSource"
                                   query="insert into MESSAGES (DATA, SAVE_DATE)
                                          values (:payload, :saveDate)"
                                   sql-parameter-source-factory="spelSource" />

<bean id="spelSource" class="o.s.i.j.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
         <map>
              <entry key="payload" value="payload" />
              <entry key="saveDate" value="new java.util.Date()" />
         </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But I get the SQLException on the payload:

> ORA-01461 can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column.

Ch. 18 of the documentation has a blob example with the whole thing rewritten as a service activator instead of an oubound-channel-adapter, and streaming from a file... that seems like overkill, but is that the way BLOBs and CLOBS are  supposed to be done in the framework?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
<entry key="payload" value="new org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.SqlLobValue(payload)" />
```

?

See its JavaDoc:

```
 * Object to represent an SQL BLOB/CLOB value parameter. BLOBs can either be an
 * InputStream or a byte array. CLOBs can be in the form of a Reader, InputStream
 * or String. Each CLOB/BLOB value will be stored together with its length.
 * The type is based on which constructor is used. Objects of this class are
 * immutable except for the LobCreator reference. Use them and discard them.
```

**UPDATE**

> "SqlLobValue only supports SQL types BLOB and CLOB", which originates from the SqlLobValue.setTypeValue(...) method.

Looks like there is no default `sqlType` for the `SqlLobValue`, so we should do something manually on the `SqlParameterSource` level since exactly that one provides a `getSqlType()` contract.

We can simply do that with the `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` extension:

```
public class MyExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory extends ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory {
    @Override
    public SqlParameterSource createParameterSource(Object input) {
        AbstractSqlParameterSource parameterSource =
                (AbstractSqlParameterSource) super.createParameterSource(input);
        parameterSource.registerSqlType("payload", Types.BLOB);
        return parameterSource;
    }
}
```

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) to add `setSqlTypes()` support to the `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work - you get an erroneous IllegalArgumentException "SqlLobValue only supports SQL types BLOB and CLOB", which originates from the SqlLobValue.setTypeValue(...) method.


It appears this happens if there's no sqlType set, that is, either BLOB or CLOB.  Tracing backwards, I don't see a way to inject that into the bean without having the Prepared Statement already...

Comment: Good catch! See an **UPDATE** in my answer.

Comment: Yep, that fixes it, thank you Artem, I appreciate it!